# imageMagick: Using Variable instead of Constant as Parameter in bash script

Tags: imagemagick, parameter-passing

I am using the following command sequence (which works pretty well)

```
convert $PIC -extent ${PIC_PX}x${PIC_PY}+0+0 \
  '(' +clone -alpha transparent -draw 'circle 1920,1080 1920,0' ')' \
  -compose copyopacity -composite circle.png
```

Now I want to substitute constants by variables

```
Var1=1920;
Var2=1080;
Var3=1920;
Var4=0
```

Can you help me with the right notation, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The semicolons in your variable assignments are superfluous. Also, always double-quote shell variables that you are expanding, i.e. `convert "$PIC" ...` and note that the shell reserves variables named in all uppercase letters for its own internal use.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick 6, that would be the following. But you need to change your single quotes on the -draw arguments to double quotes.

```
convert $PIC -extent ${PIC_PX}x${PIC_PY}+0+0 \
  '(' +clone -alpha transparent -draw "circle ${Var1},${Var2} ${Var3},0" ')' \
  -compose copyopacity -composite circle.png
```

Comment: You should also upvote it, btw.